# Getting 2 or more values then Checking them to be integer

Tags: java

How can I get 2 or more integer values of user with Scanner class then check them; if they all are integer, run some statements and if aren't just show a warning not crash!

I wrote this code but it can't be ok with Java! Of course I know where is the problem from. I only want something like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
 String v1 = sc.nextLine() ;
 System.out.println("Enter the second value: ") ;
 String v2 = sc.nextLine() ;

 if(v1.hasNextInt() && v2.hasNextInt()){ }
```

Comment: `sc.nextInt()` will get you the next `int` in the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
 int v1 = sc.nextInt() ; // could also use hasNextInt() before this line
 System.out.println("Enter the second value: ") ;
 int v2 = sc.nextInt() ;// could also use hasNextInt() before this line
// you have 2 int values..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sc.nextInt()` for taking  input as an `integer`
However if you want to take input as a `string` then
just use `Integer.parseInt(String value);`
This method will take String value as an argument and convert it to Integer.However If the String value can be converted to integer then fine,else this method throws `NumberFormatException` which you can `catch` by implementing **Exception Handling** and avoid your program from crashing.

> See various ,methods of Scanner class for taking different type of
>   input

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    integer = in.nextInt();
        longInteger = in.nextLong();
        realNumber = in.nextFloat();
        doubleReal = in.nextDouble();
        string1 = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Looks better (retracts DV). But for future readers, in Java program design the use of `Exception`s are discouraged over pre-verification (e.g. by using libraries or regex).

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` has some great utility methods for checking strings. In this scenario I would do:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first value: ");
    String v1 = sc.nextLine() ;
    System.out.println("Enter the second value: ") ;
    String v2 = sc.nextLine() ;

    if(StringUtils.isNumeric(v1) && StringUtils.isNumeric(v2)){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.matches("-?\\d+")` expression on a `String` to check whether it's an `Integer`.

```
{
    int number;
    if (v1.matches("-?\\d+"))
        number = Integer.parseInt(v1);
    else
        System.out.println("It's not a number!")
}
```